# Change Font of TextView in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm pretty new in java and android, the problem that i'm facing is that i can't change the font of another layout.

okay i have a `ListView` and i use the `ArrayAdapter` to connect another layout to my `ListView`. like image bellow:
[image]

I copy my font to `assets` folder and write this inside `onCreate`:

```
// list of titles
String[] pizza_titles = {"BBQ Bacon Cheeseburger", "Old-Fashioned Meatbrawl", "7-Alarm Fire", "Sweet Sriracha Dynamite","Cock-A-Doodle Bacon"};

// getting the ListView ID
pizza_list_view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_Pizza);

// creating ArrayAdapter and connecting the layout to ListView as well as list of string to a TextView 
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String (this,R.layout.food_row,R.id.text_food_title,pizza_titles);
pizza_list_view.setAdapter(adapter);

// defining the font typeface
Typeface pizza_title_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"pizza.ttf");
TextView pizza_title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_food_title);
pizza_title.setTypeface(pizza_title_font );
```

once i run this i get error, i guess because i set the `setTypeface` to layout that connected to `ListView`, but if i `setTypeface` to a `TextView` that is in my `activity_main`, it will work perfectly. like image bellow.

[image]

so what am i missing? and how can i solve this issue?

**Edit_1:** here the xml code of `food_row` layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/food_preview"
        android:id="@+id/image_food"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:id="@+id/text_food_title" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/text_food_description" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

here the `activity_main` xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="domain.bernard.task_02.MainActivity"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="317dp"
        android:id="@+id/listView_Pizza"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="302dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Update:**

[image]

Comment: put your adapter code ( xml & java )

Comment: you need a custom adapter to set `Typeface` to `TextView`

Comment: @Amir I've update my question and also the `food_row` is only layout which is connected to `ListView`.

Comment: @Anders custom adapter? how can i do that?

Comment: also put your error :)

Comment: @Bear check my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create your own Custom Adapter and in `getView` of your Adapter you can set the fonts, here is the example

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null)
        vi = lif.inflate(R.layout.inflate, null);
    imageView = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imageForImageView);

    TextView pizza_title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_food_title);
    pizza_title.setText("Your text");

    final Typeface pizza_title_font  = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"pizza.ttf");
    pizza_title.setTypeface(pizza_title_font);

    return vi;
}
```

if you dunno how to create Custom Adapter then you can use [this](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) library for that, its pretty straight forward

Include the dependency in your `gradle.build`

```
dependencies {
compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
}
```

create a folder in your assets folder named fonts, e.g `assets/fonts` and move your fonts in that folder and then in your `TextView`

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    fontPath="fonts/pizza.ttf"
    android:id="@+id/text_food_title" />
```

**Remeber:** it won't give you live preview of your fonts in `XML` preview but you can check it by running your app in emulate or device.

Comment: how did you load `getAssets()` for `createFromAsser` inside Custom Adapter? it keep giving me error.

Comment: that was an example, you need to Context to get assets, something like `getContext().getAssets()`

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to fix some part of your code :

- You define **weightSum** in your root layout but didn't specify layout_weight in your children.
- For using custom font I really recommend to use [This](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) library.
- Also as Andres suggest instead of ArrayAdapter use Custom Adapter to have more power on customizing.